# How to speed up random array generation in python

Tags: python-2.7, math, optimization, numerical-methods, montecarlo

I want to use the Monte-Carlo integration method to find the volume of an n-sphere and compare it to the analytical result. I want to do this for 10^6 points and 10^9 points and while it works for 10^6 points somewhat (takes about a minute for n = 2 (circle) , n = 3 (sphere) and n = 12), it is awfully slow for 10^9 points.

Short explanation of MC-Method: To find the Volume of a n-Sphere with radius r = 1, I imagine an easy known Volume (say a n-cube with sides of length 2*r) which fully contains the n-sphere. Then I sample from a uniform distribution points in the n-cube and check, if the point lies in the sphere. I count all the so generated points inside the n-sphere. The ratio of V_sphere/V_cube can be approximated as N_inside/N_total and therefore, V_sphere = V_cube * N_inside/N_total

Here is the function:

```
def hyp_sphere_mc(d,samples):    

    inside = 0                     #number of points inside sphere                                             
    sum = 0                        #sum of squared components

    for j in range(0,samples):        

        x2 = np.random.uniform(0,1,d)**2     #generate random point in d-dimensions                           
        sum = np.sum(x2)                     #sum its components

        if(sum < 1.0):                                              
            inside += 1                      #count points inside sphere

    V = ((2)**d)*(float(inside)/samples)     #V = V_cube * N_inside/N_total           

    V_true = float(math.pi**(float(d)/2))/math.gamma(float(d)/2 + 1) #analytical result 

    ERR = (float(abs(V_true-V))/V_true)*100        #relative Error

    print "Numerical:", V, "\t" , "Exact: ", V_true, "\t", "Error: ", ERR
```

I guess the problem is, that for every iteration, I generate a new random array and this takes a lot of time, especially if I have 10^9 iterations. Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: Are surprised by the execution time exploding when you as asking a thousand times more points ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the loop with the following:

```
inside = np.sum(np.sum(np.random.rand(samples,d)**2,1)<1)
```

When using numpy you should try to avoid loops. The idea is that you can just generate all the samples at once in a matrix, and then vectorize all subsequent operations.

Comment: I just tried this and it reduced the time for 10^6 points from about 1-2 min to 1 sec and 10^8 points to about 1 1/2 min compared to where I would wait 30 min and still wouldn't get a result. Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Eren Great! Remember that numpy is all about eliminating loops by using vectorization. It may take a while to get used to this form of thinking, but it is worth it (as you saw).